# Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column in field list is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql

I have a complex query  and i saw many questions in stackoverflow like this but didnt found what is the problem with my query, i'm getting this error

> "Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'orders_id' in field list
>   is ambiguous'"

when i try to execute

```
 SELECT order_process_status.process_status_id,
   orders.orders_due_date,
   order_process_status.process_status_class,
   order_process_status_description.process_status_title,
   Group_concat(DISTINCT Concat(orders.orders_id, '||',
   orders.order_id_type, '||',
   IF(orders.orders_due_date IS NULL, '', orders.orders_due_date), '||',
   IF(orders.orders_due_date IS NULL,
   '', IF(orders.orders_due_date < '2016-10-06', 'due',
   IF(orders.orders_due_date =
   '2016-10-06', 'today', IF(orders.orders_due_date = '2016-10-06' +
   INTERVAL 1 day
   , 'tomorrow', ''))))) ORDER BY orders_id DESC) AS orders_id
FROM   order_process_status
   LEFT JOIN order_process_status_description
          ON order_process_status.process_status_id =
                       order_process_status_description.process_status_id
             AND order_process_status_description.site_language_id = 1
   LEFT JOIN orders
          ON order_process_status.process_status_id =
             orders.orders_status_id
             AND orders.order_approval_status = '0'
             AND orders.orders_date_finished > Date_sub(Now(),
                                               INTERVAL 1 month)
   LEFT JOIN orders_products
     ON orders_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id
WHERE  orders.store_id = 1
   AND ( orders.admin_id IS NULL
          OR orders.admin_id = 1 )
   AND orders_products.template_type != -1
   AND order_process_status.status_type = '0'
   AND dashboard_visibility = '1'
   AND process_status_complete != 1
   AND process_status_cancel != 1
GROUP  BY order_process_status.process_status_id
ORDER  BY process_sort_order
```

I'm getting this problem when i try to add this left join

> LEFT JOIN orders_products
>            ON orders_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id

What i'm doing wrong here? please suggest me one way

Comment: I cannot detailedly look at your statement but this error occurs only when you have same column name in two different tables, specify which table it belongs to will be helpful

Comment: Use `ORDER BY orders.orders_id DESC` inside your call to `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: it worked @TimBiegeleisen. Thanks a lot!!!!!. i was looking for this issue since long.

Comment: I know that it is a duplicate question @TimBiegeleisen. But i cant even find what i did wrong in my query

Comment: You referred to column `orders_id`, but there were probably several tables in scope which had a column by that name.  By prefixing with the table name/alias, you resolved this to refer to just one known column.

Comment: Yes @TimBiegeleisen. No problem for the duplicate tag. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I actually didn't mark this as duplicate, I voted to close because it just has a simple typo.  You can thank @drew for the duplicate mark :-)

Comment: If it brought any negative vibes, then definitely hold Tim responsible :p

Comment: haha. no problem @Drew :)